# Differentiation Practical Problem with equation of motion. Maths methods

Tags: derivatives

So I am having a bit of trouble with this question. I get that I have to use optimisation but I am not sure how.
'find the least area of sheet metal required to make an open baking dish of square base and vertical sides capacity 2048cm cubed.
I have tried to use optimisation by making the lenght times width times height formula = 2048, but I don't think that is what I should be doing. It is confusing me because there are so many unknown varliables.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I am really sorry, what do I need to add for it to be ok?

Comment: Tell us what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

It is open container so there are $5$ surfaces. Now say the side of the square base is $x$ and height of the container is $y$

Given volume $V = x^2y = 2048$ ...(i).

You need to minimize the surface area as you need to use least amount of metal sheet.

Total surface area $S = x^2 + 4xy$ ...(ii)

$S = x^2 + \frac{2048 \times 4}{x}$ (substituting value of $y$ from (i))

At extrema, $\frac{dS}{dx} = 2x - \frac{2048 \times 4}{x^2} = 0 \implies x^3 = 4096$

This gives you $x = 16$ (side of the square base) and from (i), you can find the height which comes to $8$.

Now you can find minimum $S$ using (ii) (you can also do second derivative test to make sure this is minima, which it is).